# Как передавать переносы строк в Django?

Tags: python, django

Делаю что-то в роде новостного сайта на Django, поэтому сами посты выкладываются через администрирование Django. Если я вставляю подобный текст:

> **МОСКВА, 6 мая — РИА Новости. В Свердловской области загорелись склады с порохом, сообщил РИА Новости представитель экстренных
> служб.**
>
> **"Поступила информация о взрывах на складах с порохом в Ржевском городском округе", — рассказал собеседник агентства.**
>
> **По его словам, вероятная причина — переход огня с лесного пожара на находящиеся рядом складские помещения.**

То в самой админке он выглядит так же, в соблюдением отступов. Но, если я выкладываю пост, то на сайте выглядит так:

> **МОСКВА, 6 мая — РИА Новости. В Свердловской области загорелись склады с порохом, сообщил РИА Новости представитель экстренных служб.** **"Поступила информация о взрывах на складах с порохом в Ржевском городском округе", — рассказал собеседник агентства.** **По его словам, вероятная причина — переход огня с лесного пожара на находящиеся рядом складские помещения.**

Назревает вопрос: как оставлять переносы строк?

Comment: Django ничего не делает с переносами строк. Если вы пихаете текст в html-код, то не забывайте, что браузер (не Django!) в соответствии со стандартом html преобразует все пробельные символы в один пробел, и если вы хотите оставить переносы строк как есть, то вам нужно или менять css white-space, или пихать <br/> или типа того